# Check of directory to be created at specific path

Tags: linux, shell-script

I want to add some check so that user can only create the directory on specific path same as his User ID. No other directory name should be allowed.

For example :

```
path : /local/users/
User 1 : abc
User 2 : xyz
```

So in path User 1 should only be able to create directory name as "abc" (`/local/users/abc`)

User 2 should only be able to create directory name as "xyz" (`/local/users/xyz`)

How to make this possible.

Comment: Make `/local/users/USERNAME` the home directory of `USERNAME` and don't give permissions to write elsewhere?

Comment: What @Kusanalanda says. The OS should take care of that for you, no need for a script tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do exactly this with the default *nix permissions model. If someone can create a directory within /some/path, they can create *any* directory within that path. You *might* be able to use a permissions framework on top of that such as SELinux or AppArmor, or you could create a suid binary which only does this one job of creating a directory using the username of the caller.

What is more interesting is *why* you would want this. For one thing, you can simply create these directories for those users beforehand or as part of user setup, and give them ownership at that point.

Comment: We have one big sized partition /local/users where all users can create their temporary files under directory same as their user name (/local/users/<USER_Name>. For example : user xyz should keep his files under /local/users/xyz . But currently user can create directories with other names too.  I basically want restrict this so that I can actually get usage of each directory under /local/users and notify them about high usage.

Comment: The easiest way then is to just create the directories in advance with the appropriate owner.

Comment: But that doesnt stop the user to create directory with some other name. I want restrict creation of directories with name other than users "user name".

Comment: Huh? You just make the parent directory, /local/users in your case, not writeable by any of these users.

Comment: But with this then new users wont be able to create directory same as their user ID.

Comment: I'm telling you you can *create those directories beforehand,* making the point about them being able to create them entirely moot. If this does not solve the issue then [please explain what you are actually trying to do](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).